# get value attribute of a checkbox from javascript function

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

I am doing this :

```
function GETVALUE() 
{
 if(document.getElementById("requirenewpage").checked == true)
    {
        document.getElementById("requirenewpage").value;    
        var cval= parseInt(document.getElementById("requirenewpage").value);

    }
}
```

HTML-----------------------------

```
<input type="checkbox" id="requirenewpage" unchecked   value= "GETVALUE();" >
```

I need to insert into a mysql table , 0 or 1, which is taken from the VALUE attribute of the checkbox.....but am not able to do it...please help???

Its always inserting **0**  into the database, albeit am setting the value as 1 in the function GETVALUE().....

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Inputs (if they are checkboxes or radio buttons) have a `checked` attribute (which should be specified as just the **unquoted** value `checked`). If it is to be unchecked, then don't specify the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm shocked that nobody has answered this correctly yet... 
Change the checkbox to the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="requirenewpage" name="requirenewpage" value= "1" />
```

The ID of an input element is used for script access and styling *only*, if you want to submit the element in a form it must have a name attached to it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need any of this i think. You can use this html:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="requirenewpage"  value= "1" >
```

and the checkbox will send a value of 1 to the server **if  checked**,  otherwise it won't send anything (and the corresponding `$_POST['requirenewpage']` or `$_GET['requirenewpage']` won't be set).

If the checkbox is checked it's value is sent to the server and a key in the $_POST array (if you use POST) is created with the name of the checkbox and the value of hte checkbox.

you can do, serverside:

```
$chkboxval = 0;

if (isset($_POST['requirenewpage'])){
     $chkboxval = $_POST['requirenewpage'];
}
```

Comment: ----what will this do sir, ----- isset($_POST['requirenewpage']  , does it checks that checkbox is checked or unchecked , and iS TRUE, if checkbox is checked??

Comment: how do i take the value=1 of checkbox in a variable......i did this ----- $val = $_POST('requirenewpage'); ----------will $val be 1 in this case?

Comment: Yes isset($_POST['requirenewpage']) returns true if the checkbox is checked because if the checkbox is checked it's value is sent to the server and a key in the $_POST array (if you use POST) is created with the name of the checkbox. and yes $val will be 1 (or whatever value you set as the value of the checkbox)

Comment: so , there is no need to take a $chkboxval variable, which you  have taken in your code, i will just insert $val=$_POST('requirenewpage') in my mysql table

Comment: No you should always check if it's set because otherwise it's key is undefined and you will get a notice: i updated the answer you should do as written there.

Comment: sir, its inserting 0 in the database, i dont know why

Comment: try to post your full code, the error might be in the php part

Comment: sir, this line has some error------there is a blank value........in the variable---$RequiresNewPage = $_POST['requirenewpage']; ......even when the checkbox is checked.......

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1511/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-nicola-peluchetti)

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong with your html. Change your `checkbox` code from

```
<input type="checkbox" id="requirenewpage" "unchecked"   value= "GETVALUE();" >
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" id="requirenewpage" onclick= "GETVALUE();" >
```

Comment: you are right with this, but i think that's a lot more complicated than using standard html